# How is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2+3x-x²}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)²}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I was trying to find the derivative of $arcsin (2x-3)$ when i noticed that my result differed from the solution given in my book. I went to check with wolfram alpha which tells me that my format is correct as well.

However I fail to see how these two functions are equal. I can't rework my result to the one given in my book and I fail to see why.

My result is the second one in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x-3)^2}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - 4x^2 + 12x - 9}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{-8 + 12 x - 4x^2}}
$$
If you divide by $2$ on the top and $\sqrt 4$ on the bottom:
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{-8 + 12 x - 4x^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-2 + 3 x - x^2}}
$$

Comment: Ah I tried this method but didn't realise I had to divide by $\sqrt{4}$ on the bottom! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
-2+3x-x^2=-\left[x^2-3x+2 \right]=-\left[\left(x-\frac32\right)^2-\frac94+2 \right]=-\frac14\left[\left(2x-3\right)^2-1 \right]
$$ then one may apply the square root.

Answer (score 1):

$$-2+3x-x^2 =\frac{-8+12x-4x^2}4$$
$$=\frac{-8-(4x^2-12x)}4$$
$$=\frac{-8+9-(4x^2-12x+9)}4$$
$$=\frac{1-(2x-3)^2}4$$
Now take square roots and reciprocals.